# 256 colors in vim and How to install new color scheme

Tags: vim, vi, color-scheme

I'm under Ubuntu 64 bit 13.04, I'm starting with vim and I don't understand an error that I'm getting

> Error detected while processing distinguished.vim: line   16: The
>   distinguished color scheme requires gvim or a 256-color terminal Press
>   ENTER or type command to continue

As you can guess I'm trying to use a new colorscheme that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-distinguished/blob/develop/colors/distinguished.vim) , I saved it under `~/.vim/colors/` and It's my understanding that this `.vimrc` is fine for what I'm trying to do:

```
colorscheme distinguished
```

Obiviously I have more than 256 colors available on my system and I have millions of colors for my display, so what it's this about and how I can make a correct use of this colorscheme ?

Comment: It worked fine for me on Raring 64-bit. This http://askubuntu.com/questions/67/how-do-i-enable-full-color-support-in-terminal may be relevant. My ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal has been stomped on by so many versions that perhaps it just does the right thing. Alternatively, I've seen some notes somewhere that disabling "use system colors" in Edit→Profile Preference may matter.

Comment: In addition to `syntax on` you could take a look at `filetype plugin on`. It adds per-filetype configuration that'll further Vim's ability to interpret different programming languages and special filetypes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a terminal application that supports 256 colors, and a `TERM` environment variable that also points to a 256-color terminfo.  The number of colors available to your terminal has nothing to do with the rest of your setup :)

Try in your console:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
vim
```

It might not work with your terminal program, but for recent versions of xterm, it does.

[Terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) vary a lot in their capabilities; some terminals are very dumb (think of a keyboard with a line printer); some are very narrow, some are paginated, some support underlining, some have colours, some have unusual keyboard mappings, and so on.  To support all of these, there needs to be a database of capabilities for each terminal, so that applications know what they can and cannot do; that's the point of terminfo and of TERM.  By declaring `TERM=xterm-256color` you're indicating to applications that your terminal supports the xterm capabilities including 256 colors.  You can have a look in your /usr/share/terminfo/ directory to see the incredible number of terminals that are supported by your box, and `man terminfo` will show you the sheer number of configurable options for terminals.

Comment: this makes it work, but i don't get the point of this, can you expand your answer a little bit more ? what is `xterm-256color`, the value of TERM ?

Comment: It needs to be done every time. How it can be permanently applied?

Comment: export TERM="xterm-256color" add this to $Home/.bashrc file for permanent solution.  run #tput colors and verify you have 256

Answer (score 2):

Did you put distinguished.vim under ~/.vim/colors?

If you put the directory vim-distinguished there, it would not work.

Also I think you need to have the following line in .vimrc

```
syntax on
```

Comment: that's the complete path `~/.vim/colors/distinguished.vim` for the file, I don't get if it's ok or not.

Comment: that sure be fine.  Do you have `syntax on` in .vimrc?

Comment: filling the TERM environment variable fixed the issue although I still don't have `syntax` turned on